# CodeIgniter. Can I use PHP's native session functions and $_SESSION?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I've just started using CodeIgniter 2. I resisted a framework for so long but have finally realised that my mish mash collection of classes, functions, config files is a nightmare to keep updated across multiple projects.

I was looking at CI's [session class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html) and noticed the following:

> A useful aspect of the session array is that you can add your own data to it and it will be stored in the user's cookie. Why would you want to do this?

Arrrgghh! That sounds so wrong to me for so many reasons. Here's my question...
Is it possible to use PHP's native session functions and access `$_SESSION` when using CodeIgniter?
Or is there something in CI that will prevent me from doing so? Any security features that deny direct access to super globals or something?

[I found this](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/Native-session) but it looks like it's designed for CI 1.5 and I'm not sure how updated it would be. I think I would prefer to use my own wrappers for PHP's native sessions - if I can actually use PHP's native sessions.

I should also add that I'd prefer not to store sessions in a DB either, in case of connectivity/latency issues.

Comment: There is nothing that is preventing you from using `$_SESSION` within your CI applications from my understanding...

Comment: is it possible to use? why haven't you tried?

Comment: I'm using the linked native session library with CI 2.1.3, works ok.

Comment: @ZathrusWriter I have a few questions that haven't had satisfactory answers. I don't feel it's appropriate to accept an answer that hasn't actually answered my question. I'd prefer to leave it open for someone else to complete. Also there are some good comments here but I can't accept a comment as an answer.

Comment: @benjobradley why not group up those comments and self-answer the question then? it would be much more helpful for people searching for an answer than for them to search through comments, possibly not even knowing some of them are helpful

Comment: @ZathrusWriter Is that allowed, so I get the rep and the original commenters don't? I guess it's their fault for commenting rather than answering. Surely someone searching for an answer would look at comments that have received upvotes. Definition of an upvoted comment is one that is useful/helpful. I prefer to self-answer once I have a complete answer and strategy as to how I solved the problem. I believe this is more useful to people than just copy and pasting come comments. Also I don't think it would be appropriate to self-answer in the way you suggest when a question is less than 1h old.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside `config.php` there is a option which is default to use cookies:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'cookie';
```

**Description**

```
'sess_driver'= the driver to load: cookie (Classic), native (PHP sessions),
```

So it looks like you could change this to use native PHP sessions.

Comment: Ahh - it must be something that is coming since I noticed this in the latest sources on Github

Comment: https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/application/config/config.php

Comment: Awesome! I also just found this... https://github.com/danmontgomery/codeigniter-session-driver but will wait for it to drop in the next version. I know they probably had reasons for not using PHP's native sessions, but to not offer it as an option seems bonkers. Especially when CI's session id generator seems weak compared to using 256bits from /dev/urandom and sha256/sha512

Answer (score 4):

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Codeigniter session class creates it's own session data. So it has nothing to do with PHP's native session and yes you can use them.

One benefit is that you can easily save youre session data in the database.